# How to add a string within a "for loop" that is specific to each iteration?

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration

want to add the minutes that correlate with calories burned at the end of the string

want it to say "You burned x calories on the treadmill in y minutes."

```
calories burned per minute = 4.2

for numbers in [10,15,20,25,30]: # in minutes
    print('You burned', numbers * 4.2, 'calories on the treadmill. ')
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: why not expand your existing print statement? `print('You burned', numbers * 4.2, 'calories on the treadmill in' , numbers, "minutes.")` then?

Answer (score -1):

if I understand your question correctly, you want to do something like this:

```
numbers = [10,15,20,25,30]  # This list could as well be a parameter in some function
for number in numbers:
    print('You burned ' + str(number*4.2) + ' calories in ' + str(number) + ' minutes')
```

Anyway, there are various ways to format Strings in Python and that is not, in my opinion, the best. So you could replace that line with:

```
print(f'You burned {number*4.2} calories in {number} minutes')
```

or

```
print('You burned {} calories in {} minutes'.format(number*4.2, number))
```

or

```
print('You burned %.2f calories in %.2f minutes' % (number*4.2, number))
```

The f-format is only valid for Python 3.6+. Check [this](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/) for more information :).

Comment: Yeah that was it. I didn't realize how simple that was until I saw how to do it correctly. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

You can loop through the range of 10 to 30 with the step of 5. Then using the new string format insert the necessary calculation and output.

```
for i in range(10,31,5):
    print(f'You burned {4.2*i} calories on the treadmill in {i} minutes.')
```

Comment: You might consider not answering bad/offtopic questions. When answering with a code snippet ( which might provide some limited, immediate help) make sure to also add a [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: I was going to. I always write the code and then write the explanation. There is no reason for rating down

Comment: Thank you both for your help.